# Где хранить данные для построения графков полученные с API?

Tags: php, база-данных

Мне необходимо получать курсы валют с API различных бирж и выводить их в виде графиков у себя на сайте. Проблема в том,что количество запросов к API ограничено , следовательно нужно  сохранять данные на сервере и после передавать пользователям. Как это можно реализовать? Просто хранить в виде Json файла на сервере, или использовать какие то специализированные БД?
Вот пример данных которые мне нужны
        https://www.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=BNBBTC&interval=1m

Comment: Можно в файлик кешировать, с ним и работать.

Comment: если только вы будите иметь доступ к фалу, то файлик подойдет, главное чтобы он не оооочень "большим" был

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для удобной работы на будущее, лучше хранить в базе данных. Так как с бирж вы постоянно будет получать обновленные данные, то лучше в базе записывать все новые данные с датами изменения (скачками/интервалами). Таким образом соберете данные, которые в последствии сможете отображать не только интервалом **"сейчас"** или **"за неделю"** но и с промежутками **"01.04.2018 - 01.05.2018".**

Ну а для вывода пользователю, лучше кешировать нужные запросы уже в тот самый JSON или любым другим методом кеширования. Для оптимизации запросов к базе данных.

Comment: Какую БД посоветуете использовать для этих целей? у меня сейчас основная стоит MySQL

Comment: @Oxpa для ваших целей будет вполне. Если есть возможность, используйте [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php).